# How to write code for Custom Chrome Browser Automation in Espresso

Tags: android, kotlin, ui-automation, android-espresso, android-studio-3.0

@Test
fun customChromeBrowserTesting() {

```
    //click Run Ad button

    Thread.sleep(5000)

    onView(withId(R.id.button_reward_action)).perform(click())

    onView(withId(R.id.buttonText)).perform(click())

    onWebView()
        .withElement(DriverAtoms.findElement(Locator.NAME, "__CONFIRM__"))
        .perform(DriverAtoms.webClick())


}
```

This is the error message i'm getting.

androidx.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1736)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.EspressoExceptionHandler.handleSafely(EspressoExceptionHandler.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.EspressoExceptionHandler.handleSafely(EspressoExceptionHandler.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$TypedFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:11)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.doEval(Web.java:3)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.withElement(Web.java:2)
at com.digital.zocket.ui.splash.LoginTests.runAdThroughReward(LoginTests.kt:774)